# Sorting Select box with jQuery

Tags: jquery, sorting, drop-down-menu

I have a select box on a form, which carries an incremental rel attribute.
I have a function that can sort the options by thier .text() value, into alphabetcal order.

My question is, with jQuery, how do i sort in an ascending order using the rel attribute ?

```
<option rel="1" value="ASHCHRC">Ashchurch for Tewkesbury </option>
<option rel="2" value="EVESHAM">Evesham </option>
<option rel="3" value="CHLTNHM">Cheltenham Spa </option>
<option rel="4" value="PERSHOR">Pershore </option>
<option rel="5" value="HONYBRN">Honeybourne </option>
<option rel="6" value="MINMARS">Moreton-in-Marsh </option>
<option rel="7" value="GLOSTER">Gloucester </option>
<option rel="8" value="GTMLVRN">Great Malvern </option>
<option rel="9" value="MLVRNLK">Malvern Link </option>
```

my sort function:  var object; can be one of many select boxes throughout the form.

```
$(object).each(function() {

    // Keep track of the selected option.
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();

    // sort it out
    $(this).html($("option", $(this)).sort(function(a, b) { 
        return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1 
    }));

    // Select one option.
    $(this).val(selectedValue);

});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to sort by rel you should change your function

```
$(this).html($("option", $(this)).sort(function(a, b) { 
    var arel = $(a).attr('rel');
    var brel = $(b).attr('rel');
    return arel == brel ? 0 : arel < brel ? -1 : 1 
}));
```

edit with parseInt()

```
$(this).html($("option", $(this)).sort(function(a, b) { 
    var arel = parseInt($(a).attr('rel'), 10);
    var brel = parseInt($(b).attr('rel'), 10);
    return arel == brel ? 0 : arel < brel ? -1 : 1 
}));
```

Comment: If the rel is always going  to be numeric, you shoud `parseInt()` it - otherwise the order would be `1,10,11,12,2,3,4...`

Comment: how would i implement parseInt() intot the above function ?

Comment: yep, thats better, the first function threw up some odd result, like Rory pointed out, the parseInt() is required :D

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, the accepted answer is not complete if `option` has data or props (e.g. `.prop('selected', true)`). They will be removed after using `.html()`.

The function below is probably not optimized but it's correctly working :

```
$.fn.sortChildren = function(selector, sortFunc) {
    $(this)
    .children(selector)
    .detach()
    .sort(sortFunc)
    .appendTo($(this));
};

$('select').sortChildren('option', function(a, b) {
    // sort impl
});
```

Comment: Most definitely!  In the generic case where you don't need to iterate over multiple selects, `$('select').children().detach().sort(sortFunc).appendTo($('select'))` works quite nicely.  Beware `option` and `optgroup` in the children, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .attr() function to get the value of an attribute in jQuery. See http://api.jquery.com/attr/ for more info.

Try this:

```
$(object).each(function() {

    // Keep track of the selected option.
   var selectedValue = $(this).val();

   // sort it out
   $(this).html($("option", $(this)).sort(function(a, b) {
       var aRel = $(a).attr("rel");
       var bRel = $(b).attr("rel");
       return aRel == bRel ? 0 : aRel < bRel ? -1 : 1 
   }));

   // Select one option.
   $(this).val(selectedValue);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            var myarray=new Array();               
            $("select option").each(function()
            {
                myarray.push({value:this.value, optiontext:$(this).text()});
            });

            myarray.sort(sortfun);
            $newHmtl="";
            for(var i=0;i<myarray.length;i++)
            {

                $newHmtl+="<option rel='1' value='"+myarray[i]['value']+"'>"+myarray[i]['optiontext']+"</option>";
            }
            $("select").html($newHmtl);
        });            


        function sortfun(a,b) 
        {
            a = a['value'];
            b = b['value'];                
            return a == b ? 0 : (a < b ? -1 : 1)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed a similar solution then made ​​some changes to the original function and it worked fine.

```
function NASort(a, b) {  
    return (a.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > b.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) ? 1 : -1;
};

$('select option').sort(NASort).appendTo('select');
```