# selection sort does not work in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use a selection sort for javascript but it does not seem to work, can somebody help me please?
I create a function to sort an array,
then I get the value from the text box, and store it in an array named inputString 
then I split the array by comma, and store it in an array named inputNumbers
If in my text box exist non number, an error will be displayed otherwise display the sorted value.

```
function sortNow(form) {
    var nanExists = false;
    var inputString = document.getElementById("numberID").value;
    var inputNumbers = inputString.split(",");
    for (var a = 0; a < inputNumbers.length; a++) {
        inputNumbers[a] = parseInt(inputNumbers[a], 10);
        if (isNaN(inputNumbers[a])) {
            nanExists = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    inputNumbers = selectionSort(inputNumbers); //sort the array inputNumbers

    if (nanExists)
        form.answers.value = "Invalid Input";
    else
    {
        for(var b=0; b < inputNumbers.length; b++)
        {
            form.answers.value += inputNumbers[b];
        }
    }
    }
/* function to sort an array */
    function selectionSort(inputArray) {
    for(var i=0; i<inputArray.length; i++)
    {
        var currentMin = inputArray[i];
        var currentMinIndex = i;    
        for(var j=i+1; j<inputArray.length; j++)
        {
            if(currentMin > inputArray[j])
            {
                currentMin = inputArray[j];
                currentMinIndex = j;
            }
            if(currentMinIndex != i)
            {
                inputArray[currentMinIndex] = inputArray[i];
                inputArray[i] = currentMin;
            }
        }
    }
    return inputArray;
}
```

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887542/sorting-select-box-with-jquery

Comment: I am not familiar with jquery so i made it in javascript, and in my case, it is different from other one.

Comment: What is the specific problem?  Are you getting a javascript error?  If so, what is the error?  Is it just not sorting properly, but no errors? Also, why don't you just use javascript's `Array.sort()`?

Comment: It is not sorting properly. Can you please show me why my sort function work properly? Thank you for the info about Array.sort()

Comment: @JackyNguyen: You need to write a custom sort function because Array.sort() sorts array lexicographically (in dictionary order) according to the string conversion of each element. See the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code please move the following code segment from inner loop (j) to outer loop (i).

```
        if(currentMinIndex != i)
        {
            inputArray[currentMinIndex] = inputArray[i];
            inputArray[i] = currentMin;
        }
```

See the [demo](http://jsbin.com/ipuhiy/4/watch)

Please sort the inputArray like this:

```
inputArray.sort(function(a,b) {
  return (a > b) ? 1 : ((a == b) ? 0 : -1);
});
```

You need to supply a custom sort function to Array.sort because Array.sort() sorts array lexicographically (in dictionary order) according to the string conversion of each element.

See a working demo [here](http://jsbin.com/ipuhiy/3/watch)

Read up the [MDN:Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: @raghaw: I know of Array.sort() but can you please take a look at my sort function above to see why it does not work properly. I use the same function like that and it works in Java but when I do the same for Javascript, it does not work.