# Sorting options by value using Jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to sort the options by value in selectbox. Sorting is fine by using the below code.But i have option value null, it goes to bottom which should be at top.

```
$(this).html($("option", $(this)).sort(function(a, b) { 
    var arel = parseInt($(a).attr('value'), 10);
    var brel = parseInt($(b).attr('value'), 10);
    return arel == brel ? 0 : arel < brel ? -1 : 1 
}));
```

Source: [Sorting Select box with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887542/sorting-select-box-with-jquery)

Actual Result:

```
<select name="option[285]">
<option value="298">Blazing Yellow</option>
<option value="299">Jet Black</option>
<option value="300">Tabacco Brown</option>
<option value="301">Optical White</option>
<option value="302">Fiery Red </option>
<option value="" selected="selected"> --- Please Select --- </option>
</select>
```

Expected Result:

```
<select name="option[285]">
<option value="" selected="selected"> --- Please Select --- </option>
<option value="298">Blazing Yellow</option>
<option value="299">Jet Black</option>
<option value="300">Tabacco Brown</option>
<option value="301">Optical White</option>
<option value="302">Fiery Red </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `parseInt('')` given `NaN` which when compared using `arel < brel` gives wrong result

```
$(this).html($("option", $(this)).sort(function(a, b) { 
    var arel = parseInt($(a).attr('value'), 10) || 0;
    var brel = parseInt($(b).attr('value'), 10)|| 0;
    return arel == brel ? 0 : arel < brel ? -1 : 1 
}));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/n9L3L/)